# using react with tinymce and controlling a specific property of a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, tinymce

```js
let [detail,setDetail] = useState({'details':''}) //Specialized state for Editor element

let {details} = detail

const handleEditorChange = (e)=>{
      setDetail(
         ...detail,
         [e.target.textareaName]:e.target.value
)
}


//returning a jsx (part of the code) focus on Editor, because this where the problem occur: 


<div>
<form onSubmit={(e)=>{handleChange(e)}}>
<input name='name' value={name} onChange={(e)=>{handleChange(e)}}>

<Editor  textareaName='details' onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor} init={{
           section:'textarea',
           height: 500,
           menubar: false,
           toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
           'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
           'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
           'removeformat | help',
           content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px }'
         }} value={detail}  onEditorChange={(e)=>editorHandleChange(e)}/>
</form>
</div>
```

I have an `Editor` element from `tinymce` , this one is used for react I have a state like this for all inputs+Editor:

```js
let [someState,setSomeState] = {'name':,"year":"","detail":""}
```

now as you see `name` and `year` are controlled by normal inputs elements in jsx , but for `detail` i have to use `Editor` element,  and i really dont know how to track the editor change, plus i dont know how to set `detail` property in the state `someState` when submitting
, some code for handling the editor change:

```js
let editorHandleChange = (e)=>{
        setdet(
        {
            ...detail,
        textareaName: e.target.value 

    }
        )
}
```

it is giving me `textareaName` is undefined in console, same with `value`
any help is appreciated!!

edit: the `Editor` element has an apiKey, but i hid it here.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a react-wrapper for `tinymce`, which is described here:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/react-cloud/ - in this example, the editor content is logged to the console. Replace the call of console.log with you state setter and you should be done.

If for some reason you can not use the react wrapper, you can also try to change your code in `handleEditorChange` to access the native event: `e.nativeEvent.target.textAreaName`. I would prefer using the react-wrapper though because then you don't need to mix up browser events/the browser DOM with virtual events/the virtual DOM.

Comment: that where i got my code from, i am not sure what you are trying to provide here...

Comment: also, adding `e.nativeEvent.target.textAreaName` is just going to give me undefined property `target` in console dev.

Comment: Your code did not show the include statements, so I was assuming you are using the non-react version of tiny-mce because I saw you access the browser DOM directly. If you use the react-version already, then handleEditorChange will receive two parameters: the value and the editor, not an event.

Comment: this still did not solve anything.